# launching two different profiles maven

Tags: java, spring, maven, properties

i have defined on my maven project (ide eclipse) two profiles (Prod and CI) and when i start the install command it create a field that contains the jar files and the properties of the project. if i boot prod first and CI second it creates two distinct fields and it's ok . but if i boot together with "install prod,ci" it creates only the ci field and it makes the merge of the properties. is there any way to launch properties together and make sure it creates two fields like when i boot it separately ? thanks.

i show you the poms (the configuration of the CI is the same of PROD)
pom1 (maven collector project)

```
<!-- PROD ENVIRONMENT -->
        <profile>
            <id>profile-release</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>

                    <!-- Merge all properties into one -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <configuration>
                                    <target>
                                        <property name="maven.project.basedir"
                                            value="${project.basedir}" />
                                        <property name="maven.project.parent.build.directory"
                                            value="${project.parent.build.directory}" />
                                        <concat
                                            destfile="${maven.project.parent.build.directory}/job.properties">
                                            <fileset dir="${maven.project.basedir}/../"
                                                includes="**/target/classes/META-INF/spring/batch/props/c-job-t*.properties"></fileset>
                                        </concat>
                                    </target>
                                </configuration>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>run</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>

                    <!-- Copy all dependencies not included into CBS -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1.1</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>copy</id>
                                <phase>package</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>copy</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <configuration>
                                    <artifactItems>
                                        <artifactItem>
                                            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                                            <version>2.8.4</version>
                                            <type>jar</type>
                                            <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                            <outputDirectory>${project.parent.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                                            <destFileName>gson-2.8.4.jar</destFileName>
                                        </artifactItem>
                                        <artifactItem>
                                            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
                                            <version>2.9.9</version>
                                            <type>jar</type>
                                            <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                            <outputDirectory>${project.parent.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                                        </artifactItem>
                                        <artifactItem>
                                            <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
                                            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
                                            <version>1.11.3</version>
                                            <type>jar</type>
                                            <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                            <outputDirectory>${project.parent.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                                        </artifactItem>
                                    </artifactItems>
                                </configuration>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>

            </build>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
                <property>
                    <name>PROFILE</name>
                    <value>profile-release</value>
                </property>
            </activation>
        </profile>

pom2 (main pom)

    <profile>
                <id>profile-release</id>
                <build>
                    <plugins>
                        <!-- Copy all generate jars and dependencies not included into CBS -->
                        <plugin>
                            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                            <version>3.1.1</version>
                            <executions>
                                <execution>
                                    <id>copy</id>
                                    <phase>package</phase>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>copy</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                    <configuration>
                                        <artifactItems>
                                            <artifactItem>
                                                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                                                <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
                                                <version>${project.version}</version>
                                                <type>${project.packaging}</type>
                                                <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                                <outputDirectory>${project.parent.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                                                <destFileName>${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</destFileName>
                                            </artifactItem>
                                        </artifactItems>
                                    </configuration>
                                </execution>
                            </executions>
                        </plugin>
                    </plugins>
                </build>
                <activation>
                    <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
                    <property>
                        <name>PROFILE</name>
                        <value>profile-release</value>
                    </property>
                </activation>
                <properties>
                    <project.type.environment>commonPROD</project.type.environment>
                    <project.parent.build.directory>${project.basedir}/../c-batch-job-t/target/profile-ce</project.parent.build.directory>
                </properties>
            </profile>
```

Comment: Can you include your pom file?

Comment: dou you use `mvn install prod,ci` or  `mvn install **-P** prod,ci`?

Comment: install (goal) and prod,ci (profiles)